# Assigning Tasks

Tags: 2010, workflow, tasks

If I assign a task to an Active Directory group or mailing list, will it autogenerate tasks for each person in that group or mailing list such that they all get an individual task to complete?

---

NOTE:
This is quite literally a question of assigning a task. I.E. in the workflow, I have an item that assigns a task to an AD group. This group contains 5 people. Will each of those 5 people get an individual task to complete (marked for "In Parallel" approval such that all of them must approve), or will only one approval from one of those 5 people be enough to complete the approval step?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want display task only for assigned groups or users then you have two options.

1- Create View : Create a View that display task for that particular group.

2- Item level Permission : Break Inheritance of Task List item and assign group with permission to that task list item to auto display by share point security, where do remember item level permission has performance penalty.

Comment: See my added note to the question.

Comment: It depends on ur logic.. if you want all five should approve.. then u can use % Completed and for each approval adds 20 to %completed

Comment: can that be done with SPD workflows?  This needs to be out of the box as much as is possible, without custom coding or infopath